# StyleCop rule for checking project references

Tags: c#, stylecop, project-reference

Sometimes when updating a dll version, the references to that dll from other projects suddenly refer to the GAC instead of our custom assemblies folder. This is a problem, because a project may refer to an old dll and will not deploy on the TEST environment.

Therefore, I want to make a StyleCop rule. The rule should check whether project references point to the GAC. If they do, a warning or error should occur. I found documentation on how to create custom StyleCop rules, but I need some help to get started.

So the question: How do I access project references through StyleCop, so I can check whether they point to the GAC or not? Or do you know a tool that checks project references?

Thanks in advance